# Are these two surfaces topological equivalents?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I believe they are not the same since after deforming both, we get a surface with 5 holes in in the first picture, and a picture with 4 holes in the second picture. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first seems to be the connected sum of five tori ($S^1\times S^1$), while the second of four.

Comment: Not just "seems" but "is".

Comment: So means they are not homeomorphic?

Comment: @Emeendedor: Genus is a topological invariant, thus the surfaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @Emprendedor: I'm using the classification of compact topological surface, and they're not even homotopically equivalent.